# how to read input data (.json file)line by line using dictionary in c# --> generic code

Tags: c#, automation, jsonreader

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` to read a `.json` file. I need to generically --> It should loop through all the datas where data/count may vary every time.

```
//var map=new Dictionary<string,string>();
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(filepath)){
    using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader()){
        JObject obj = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);

        while (Reader.read()){
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.lineNumber; i++){
                if (reader.value != null)
                    Console.Writeline("Token{i},Tokem{1}", reader.TokenType, reader.TokenValue);
                else
                    Console.Writeline("Token{i}", reader.TokenValue);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to get these console values returned in a Dictionary/List to make it generic?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(File.ReadAllText(filepath));`? Could you please share the JSON your are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Actually I don't have any JSON file as of now. I'm writing framework from the scratch. So the code should loop through all datas in .json file. I didn't work with json before. I have created data access layer to read excel, xml, csv, sqlhelper, etc. and used dictionary to get data from each files. But i don't have idea to read data from json..